# Unable to upload photos in question from the Stack Exchange Android app

Tags: bug, android-app

I have uninstalled and reinstalled the app, but every time I want to upload any photo, the app replies something went wrong.

- App Version: 1.0.95
- Device Manufacturer: PANASONIC
- Device Model: ELUGA_I2

  - OS Version: 5.1 (1440411390)

Comment: No work has been done on the app for years, this isnt expected to change anytime soon. You'll just have to use a browser to add your image. Using the responsive mode works very well for me.

Comment: @Luuklag is correct, by all means the app is dead.